# JObject Parse not able to parse String with JSON type

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, parsing

In this method, a JSON String will be returned from GetDataSetColumns() which called API from a Signage System(Xibo) to get dataset. And I want to parse it to JSON Object.

I googled it many times and found some people have same problem too. But it seems their solution are not working for me. Such as parsing to JArray or String.Trim()

```
public async Task<String> GetColumnIdByName(int dataSetId, String heading)
        {
            String columns = await GetDataSetColumns(dataSetId);
            columns.Replace("[", "");
            columns.Replace("]", "");
            columns.TrimStart().TrimEnd();
            **JObject json = JObject.Parse(columns);** 
            Debug.WriteLine(json);

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, JToken> pair in json)
            {
                if (pair.Key.ToString().Equals("dataSetColumnId"))
                {
                    if(pair.Value.ToString().Equals(heading))
                    {
                        return pair.Value.ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
```

Here's the JSON returned from GETDataSetColumns method and shown in Debug.
And I cannot see there is any mistakes in this JSON String.

```
    [
    {
        "dataSetColumnId": 8,
        "dataSetId": 3,
        "heading": "item_name",
        "dataTypeId": 1,
        "dataSetColumnTypeId": 1,
        "listContent": null,
        "columnOrder": "1",
        "formula": null,
        "dataType": "String",
        "dataSetColumnType": "Value"
    },
    {
        "dataSetColumnId": 9,
        "dataSetId": 3,
        "heading": "price",
        "dataTypeId": 1,
        "dataSetColumnTypeId": 1,
        "listContent": null,
        "columnOrder": "2",
        "formula": null,
        "dataType": "String",
        "dataSetColumnType": "Value"
    },
    {
        "dataSetColumnId": 12,
        "dataSetId": 3,
        "heading": "category",
        "dataTypeId": 1,
        "dataSetColumnTypeId": 1,
        "listContent": null,
        "columnOrder": "3",
        "formula": null,
        "dataType": "String",
        "dataSetColumnType": "Value"
    },
    {
        "dataSetColumnId": 15,
        "dataSetId": 3,
        "heading": "status",
        "dataTypeId": 1,
        "dataSetColumnTypeId": 1,
        "listContent": null,
        "columnOrder": "7",
        "formula": null,
        "dataType": "String",
        "dataSetColumnType": "Value"
    }
]
```

And I also inspected the value of variable by Debugging mode, is it normal to have '\n' and many blankspaces? Moreover, the String.Replace and String.TrimStart() aren't working.

[Debugging Mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFn6v.png)

The exception error happens after JObject.Parse.

```
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
Exception thrown: 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' in mscorlib.dll
An exception of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

Is there any problem of my JSON string or the way of parsing?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: You are invalidating your json by removing [ and ]. What you have is an array and it is perfectly valid. No need to Trim either, blank space is not significant.

Comment: The JSON you've shown is already valid (you can check by inputting it at https://jsonlint.com/), you don't need to do anything to manipulate it, it's already parseable (since it's an array, JArray would be your best bet, if you don't have a specific type you want to deserialise to).

Comment: If you don't know whether your `columns` string is going to be an object or an array, you can use [`JToken.Parse(columns)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38211719/3744182) and check the result.

Comment: I tried the original JSON without removing [ and ]. But the error JsonReaderException is still happneing.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976018/parsing-multidimensional-json-array-with-newtonsoft-json-net)

I also found other answers online but all of them are not working.
Some of them proposed define a class and deserialize the object as that defined class. But I think it isn't the right way because the structure of JSON could be dynamic.

I transfer it to JArray and retrieve the objects from it as JObject.
And it works.
I saw these comments and I think the validity of JSON isn't the main point of my problem at all.

```
 String columns = await GetDataSetColumns(dataSetId);
 JArray jArr = (JArray)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(columns);

 foreach (JObject item in jArr)
 { 
    if(heading.Equals(item["heading"].ToString()))
       {
                return item["dataSetId"].ToString();
       }

 }
```

Here's example of the JSON string and I get the value by key

```
{
    "dataSetColumnId": 12,
    "dataSetId": 3,
    "heading": "category",
    "dataTypeId": 1,
    "dataSetColumnTypeId": 1,
    "listContent": null,
    "columnOrder": "3",
    "formula": null,
    "dataType": "String",
    "dataSetColumnType": "Value"
}
```